# calculate the total move distance of one turtle

Tags: netlogo, distance, pixel

I am new to Netlogo and learning a model is about animals moving around to eat grass based on the grazing model from NetLogo. The moving behavior is based on the biomass's richness, so it is not just impacting at right angles.

Given the conditions, I don't know how to add a monitor in my model that calculates the total distance a turtle moved by traveling each pixel.

Move specifically, I wonder if there is a way to calculate the total length of the pen-marked lines. (Show in the picture)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvIlM.png)

The basic setting of move is

```
to move-turtles
  uphill-biomass  
  forward 1
  set distance-traveled (distance-traveled + 1)
  if not can-move? 1 [ rt random 150 ]  
end

to uphill-biomass
  let biomass-ahead biomass-scent-at-angle   0
  let biomass-right biomass-scent-at-angle  35
  let biomass-left  biomass-scent-at-angle -35
  if (biomass-right = biomass-ahead) and (biomass-left = biomass-ahead) [ wiggle ]
  if (biomass-right > biomass-ahead) or (biomass-left > biomass-ahead)
  [ ifelse biomass-right > biomass-left
    [ rt 35 ]
    [ lt 35 ] ]
end
```

Thank you very much for any helps!

Comment: Do you want to monitor the distance of a specific turtle? If that is the case, just use `[distance-traveled] of <someturtle>` in the monitor, where <someturtle> is anything you use to identify the turtle you are interested in.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, Matteo.
No, I want to calculate the length of the specific turtle moved, not the tick.
I have tried the [distance-traveled] and it retuned as ticks only.

Comment: That in fact seems to be correct: everytime that a turtle executes `move-turtles`, it will move exactly by 1 because the command says `forward 1`. If turtles `forward 1` at every tick, then the distance covered will equal the number of ticks.

Comment: Good to know this. Please correct me if I get wrong. I used the pen to mark the path and it made me think about whether I can calculate the length of that path. As you can see attached picture, the length will not be the same as `forward 1` which refers to a pixel. Given the animal moves at different angles across pixels I think the length will be different. Do you think it is possible to measure it on NetLogo?

Comment: @Urgen `forward 1` does not refer to any patch. It simply moves the turtle exactly 1 forward. If you instead want your turtle to move to the middle of the patch in front of them, you should use `move-to patch-ahead 1` to go to the middle of the patch that encompasses the x and y coordinates exactly 1 in front of the turtle. Note that this means the turtle doesn't necessarily move to the first patch in front of itself, as it might jump over corners.

Comment: As for calculating the length of a drawn path: as far as I know, a drawn path is purely visual and you can't use it as input for other procedures. If you want to calculate the length your turtle moves, you will have to give your turtle its own `turtles-own` variable with which you register how far it moves at each step.

Comment: By the way, what is up with `rt random 150`? That seems like a very arbitrary number to use

Comment: I got it, thank you for the explanation! As for rt random 150, I want the turtle to turn around at a bigger dredge.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use some turtle variables with the `turtles-own` primitive and do the distance calculation by hand.

The easiest way to do such a calculation is to save the coordinates between a turtle's previous coordinates with turtle variables and then use the `distancexy` primitive (link for dictionary entry: https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#distancexy)

Here's a simple implementation:

```
turtles-own [last-x last-y distance-traveled]


move-turtle
  uphill-biomass  
  
  set last-x xcor
  set last-y ycor
  
  forward 1
  
  set distance-traveled (distance-traveled + (distancexy last-x last-y))
  
  if not can-move? 1 [ rt random 150 ]  
end
```

I hope this answers your question.